# Error en una linea de código ayuda para resolverla

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <String.h>
using namespace std;
class CParticipante {
 private:
  char *nombre;
  char *apellido;
  char sexo;
  char *lugar_nacimiento;
  char *pais_residencia;
  char *doc_identidad;
  char *telefono;
  char *e_mail;

 public:
  CParticipante();
  CParticipante(const char *, const char *, char, const char *, const char *,
                const char *, const char *, const char *);
  //~CParticipante();
  CParticipante(const CParticipante &);
  CParticipante &operator=(const CParticipante &);
  void SetParticipante(char *, char *, char, char *, char *, char *, char *,
                       char *);
  // void GetParrticipante(char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char *,char
  // *);const;
};
CParticipante::CParticipante() {
  nombre = NULL;
  apellido = NULL;
  sexo = 0;
  lugar_nacimiento = NULL;
  pais_residencia = NULL;
  doc_identidad = NULL;
  telefono = NULL;
  e_mail = NULL;
}

CParticipante::CParticipante(const char *nomb, const char *apell, char sex,
                             const char *l_nac, const char *p_re,
                             const char *Doc_id, const char *tel,
                             const char *correo) {
  nombre = new char[strlen(nomb) + 1];
  strcpy(nombre, nomb);
  apellido = new char[strlen(apell) + 1];
  strcpy(apellido, apell);
  sexo = sex;
  lugar_nacimiento = new char[strlen(l_nac) + 1];
  strcpy(lugar_nacimiento, l_nac);
  pais_residencia = new char[strlen(p_re) + 1];
  strcpy(pais_residencia, p_re);
  doc_identidad = new char[strlen(Doc_id) + 1];
  strcpy(doc_identidad, Doc_id);
  telefono = new char[strlen(tel) + 1];
  strcpy(telefono, tel);
  e_mail = new char[strlen(correo) + 1];
  strcpy(e_mail, correo);
}

CParticipante::CParticipante(const CParticipante &cp) {
  nombre = new char[strlen(cp.nombre) + 1];
  strcpy(nombre, cp.nombre);
  apellido = new char[strlen(cp.apellido) + 1];
  strcpy(apellido, cp.apellido);
  sexo = cp.sexo;
  lugar_nacimiento = new char[strlen(cp.lugar_nacimiento) + 1];
  strcpy(lugar_nacimiento, cp.lugar_nacimiento);
  pais_residencia = new char[strlen(cp.pais_residencia) + 1];
  strcpy(pais_residencia, cp.pais_residencia);
  doc_identidad = new char[strlen(cp.doc_identidad) + 1];
  strcpy(doc_identidad, cp.doc_identidad);
  telefono = new char[strlen(cp.telefono) + 1];
  strcpy(telefono, cp.telefono);
  e_mail = new char[strlen(cp.e_mail) + 1];
  strcpy(e_mail, cp.e_mail);
}

CParticipante &CParticipante::operator=(const CParticipante &cp) {
  nombre = new char[strlen(cp.nombre) + 1];
  strcpy(nombre, cp.nombre);
  apellido = new char[strlen(cp.apellido) + 1];
  strcpy(apellido, cp.apellido);
  sexo = cp.sexo;
  lugar_nacimiento = new char[strlen(cp.lugar_nacimiento) + 1];
  strcpy(lugar_nacimiento, cp.lugar_nacimiento);
  pais_residencia = new char[strlen(cp.pais_residencia) + 1];
  strcpy(pais_residencia, cp.pais_residencia);
  doc_identidad = new char[strlen(cp.doc_identidad) + 1];
  strcpy(doc_identidad, cp.doc_identidad);
  telefono = new char[strlen(cp.telefono) + 1];
  strcpy(telefono, cp.telefono);
  e_mail = new char[strlen(cp.e_mail) + 1];
  strcpy(e_mail, cp.e_mail);
  return *this;
}

void CParticipante::SetParticipante(
    char *nomb, char *apell, char sex, char *l_nac, char *p_re, char *Doc_id,
    char *tel,
    char *correo);  // esta linea de codigo me da error y no se como resolverla

int main() {
  CParticipante participante,
      participante2("chistina", "Miranda", 'F', "Somoto", "Nicaragua",
                    "321-141095-000p", "84486062",
                    "Christinamiranda515@gmail.com");
  int op;

  do {
    cout << "1.Introducir participante" << endl;
    cout << "2.Mostrar participante" << endl;
    cout << "3.Crear una copia del participante" << endl;
    cout << "4.Asignar un participante en otro" << endl;
    cout << "5.Salir" << endl;
    cin >> op;
    switch (op) {
      case 1:
        break;
      case 2:
        break;
      case 3:
        break;
      case 4:
        break;
      case 5:
        break;
    }
  } while (op != 5);
}
```

---

El error en esta parte:

```
void CParticipante::SetParticipante(
    char *nomb, char *apell, char sex, char *l_nac, char *p_re, char *Doc_id,
    char *tel,
    char *correo);  // esta linea de codigo me da error y no se como resolverla
```

Comment: ¿Podrías resumir qué intentas hacer en ese código y qué mensaje de error te está dando? Pásate por [**cómo preguntar**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para obtener ayuda acerca de cómo plantear correctamente una pregunta.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error? ¿En qué línea de código?

Answer (score 2):

```
void CParticipante::SetParticipante(
    char *nomb, char *apell, char sex, char *l_nac, char *p_re, char *Doc_id,
    char *tel,
    char *correo);  // esta linea de codigo me da error y no se como resolverla
```

Esa línea te da error porque el compilador está esperando encontrarse la implementación de la función y no es lo que se encuentra:

```
void CParticipante::SetParticipante(
    char *nomb, char *apell, char sex, char *l_nac, char *p_re, char *Doc_id,
    char *tel,
    char *correo)
{
  // Aqui el codigo de la funcion
}
```